# Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [EC2Instance1, EC2Instance2] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am new to cloudformation and YAML and I am trying to create 2 ec2 instances in different regions and to attach them to a load balancer

These are the parameters

```
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 Key Pair
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: Choose which VPC that the Application Load Balancer should be deployed to

  Subnets:
    Description: Choose minimum of 2 subnets (2 different availability zones) that Application Load Balancer should be deployed to
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

After that I added the ressources. The first one is the security group.

```
Resources:
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDEscription: Enable SSH access via port 22 and Enable Http via port 80
      SecurityGroupEngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

The first ec2 instance with the location in Frankfurt

```
# Frankfurt
  Ec2Instance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-043097594a7df80ec
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64':
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            yum update -y
            yum install -y httpd
            systemctl start httpd
            systemctl enable httpd
            echo "<h1> Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Second ec2 instance with the location in Virginia

```
# N. Virginia
  Ec2Instance2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0d5eff06f840b45e9
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64':
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            yum update -y
            yum install -y httpd
            systemctl start httpd
            systemctl enable httpd
            echo "<h1> Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

The code for load balancer. The ApplicationLoadBalancer:

```
  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: 'MyLoadBalancer1'
      Subnets: !Ref Subnets
      SecurityGroups: [!GetAtt SecurityGroup.GroupId]
```

After that comes the ALBListener:

```
  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
```

And the TargetGroup:

```
  ALBTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 80
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Name: MyTargets
      Targets: 
        - Id: 
            Ref: EC2Instance1
          Port: 80
        - Id: 
            Ref: EC2Instance2
          Port: 80
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do? Attach two instances in different regions to same load balancer? Also you haven't explained what is the actuall issue with templates you provided? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. After I upload the file in cloudformation, I click next and receive this error from the title

Comment: You can't do this. Instances must be in same region.

Comment: Ok, I changed and tried to create both in the same region, but I still receive the same error.

Comment: I would suggest providing full code, not some fragments of it.